# Unable to fit the website as the resolution of the screen

Tags: css, html

I'm unable to make the website fit the screen of the user, it just don't accept the changes, i tried several things but i can't find where the problem is.

### CSS.

```
<style>
.full-width-div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#texto {
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p.uno {
    text-align: center max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: 4px 2px 0px #000000;
}

a {
    color: yellow;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.wsnextlink1:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2a5db0;
}

a.wsnextlink1:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #560080;
}

a.wsnextlink1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #800000;
}

div.shadow {
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: visible;
}

img.logo {
    padding-top: 5px;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

video#bgvideo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
```

### HTML: Here is the problem the site don't fit the screen and is odd to look at.

```
<body>
<div class="full-width-div">
    <div class="shadow">
        <div id="texto">
            <p class="uno" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;letter-spacing:1pt;word-spacing:2pt;font-size:35px;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1;">

                text.</p>
        </div>

        <img src="017.jpg" class="logo">
        <div id="texto">
            <p class="uno" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;letter-spacing:1pt;word-spacing:2pt;font-size:35px;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1;">
                <a href="finish.html" align="center">

                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="texto">
            <p class="uno" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;letter-spacing:1pt;word-spacing:2pt;font-size:35px;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1;">
                <a href="017.html" align="center">


                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is it the video that doesn't fit? If you take that out and just put text in does everything scale properly? Also, is there a specific device that it does not fit in? Does it work fine for a desktop browser, but not for a handheld device?

Comment: The video fits, problem is the main image and the text under that it's out of the screen and i want it to be inside.

Comment: Try wrapping the image in a `div` as well, it may be getting shunted over. Try either moving it up into the same div as the text above it, add a `br` after the `p` block, then your `img` or just wrapping it with a `div` of its own. Same with the following `p` block, add a `br` after the `img` or wrap it with its own `div` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following, it seemed like your `div` tags weren't all closed, you may need to take a look at the `div` tags I have in here, they may need modified depending on what you want, but I think this should scale properly and keep things from sliding around:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
        .full-width-div {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }
        #texto {
                    width:100%;
                    height:51px;
                    color:white;
                    text-align:center;
                }

        p.uno {
               text-align:center
               max-width:90%;
               max-height:90%;
               color: yellow;
               text-shadow: 4px 2px 0px #000000;
               font-weight:normal;
               color:white;
               letter-spacing:1pt;
               word-spacing:2pt;
               font-size:35px;
               text-align:center;
               font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;
               line-height:1;
        }

        a{color: yellow;}
        a{text-align:center;}
        a {text-decoration: none;}
        a.wsnextlink1:link{text-decoration:none; color:#2a5db0;} 
        a.wsnextlink1:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#560080;} 
        a.wsnextlink1:hover{text-decoration:underline; color:#800000;}


        div.shadow {
                    padding-top: 5px;
                    text-align: center;
                    max-width:90%;
                    max-height:90%;
                    overflow:visible;
        }

        img.logo {
                    padding-top: 5px;
                    max-width:90%;
                    max-height:90%;       
                    border-radius: 5%;
        }

        video#bgvideo { 

          position: fixed;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          min-width: 100%;
          min-height: 100%;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          z-index: -100;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="full-width-div">
     <div>
      <div class="shadow">
       <div id="texto"><p class="uno">text.</p></div>
       <div><img src="017.jpg"  class="logo"></div>
       <div id="texto"><p class="uno"><a href="finish.html" align="center">link1</a></p></div>
       <div id="texto"><p class="uno"><a href="017.html" align="center">link2</a></p></div>    
      </div>
     </div>
     <div>
     <video id="bgvideo" autoplay loop>
      <source src="club08.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/webm">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
     </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Edit: I added a `div` around the `video` to ensure it renders as a block element as well. I think it can sometimes render as either block or in-line.

Comment: Yeah seems some problem are fixed there but, sit still don't fits the entire height of my screen, any way to go around with this?

Comment: You'll just have to do some trial and error on that one. HTML renders top-to-bottom and height adjustment isn't always reliable. Your best bet would be to have device specific CSS documents. For smaller viewports you could use a smaller font or render some things (i.e. the links) all on a single line.You could also start with taking the `height: 100%` setting off of the `full-width-div` and let it render it's own height according to its content. Is it rendering too large for the browser, or do you mean it is rendering too small and you want it to fill the entire window?